# jspm not working when trying to install packages

Tags: windows, jspm

I am having an issue when trying to use jspm when i run `jspm install` (or `jspm install jquery` or any other package for what it matters), it times out twice and then at the 3rd attempt it will show me an error message.
I'm not sure what else to say, this is my first time using jspm so i'm just going to paste the output:

```
jspm install jquery
     Updating registry cache...

warn Timed out on locate for jspm:jquery, retrying (1).
     To increase the timeout run jspm config registries.jspm.timeouts.lookup 120


warn Timed out on locate for jspm:jquery, retrying (2).
     To increase the timeout run jspm config registries.jspm.timeouts.lookup 120


warn Error on locate for jspm:jquery
     Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     From https://github.com/jspm/registry
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
     fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in
the working tree.
     Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
         at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
         at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5
)

err  Error locating jspm:jquery.
```

I am running on Windows 7 64 bit and i am under a proxy (localhost proxy without authentication that connects to corporate proxy that requires authentication), i have set up HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables and npm works fine under the proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by clearing my jspm cache. Try running this command:

`jspm cache-clear`